# g++ internal compiler error during OpenFST building

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile OpenFST:

```
wget http://distfiles.macports.org/openfst/openfst-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar -xf openfst-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd openfst-1.5.2
sudo ./configure --enable-compact-fsts --enable-const-fsts --enable-far --enable-lookahead-fsts --enable-pdt
sudo make install
```

But after long time the building fails in this way:

```
 Libraries have been installed in:    /usr/local/lib

 If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a
 given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the
 full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during
 linking and do at least one of the following:
    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
      during execution
    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
      during linking
    - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
    - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

 See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for more
 information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- make[3]: Nessuna operazione da eseguire per "install-data-am".
 make[3]: uscita dalla directory "/home/pi/src/openfst-1.5.2/src/lib"
 make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/pi/src/openfst-1.5.2/src/lib"
 Making install in script make[2]: ingresso nella directory
 "/home/pi/src/openfst-1.5.2/src/script" /bin/bash ../../libtool 
 --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./../include    -std=c++11 -MT determinize.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/determinize.Tpo -c -o determinize.lo determinize.cc libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
 -I./../include -std=c++11 -MT determinize.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/determinize.Tpo -c determinize.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o
 .libs/determinize.o g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program
 cc1plus) Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if
 appropriate. See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for
 instructions. Makefile:516: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo
 "determinize.lo" non riuscito make[2]: *** [determinize.lo] Errore 1
 make[2]: uscita dalla directory
 "/home/pi/src/openfst-1.5.2/src/script" Makefile:358: set di
 istruzioni per l'obiettivo "install-recursive" non riuscito make[1]:
 *** [install-recursive] Errore 1 make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/pi/src/openfst-1.5.2/src" Makefile:414: set di istruzioni per
 l'obiettivo "install-recursive" non riuscito make: ***
 [install-recursive] Errore 1
```

I don't understand what is the cause of the error and thus how to fix it.
The o.s. is Rapsbian Jessie Lite running on RPi3.

Comment: Actually, looks more like you ran out of RAM. Could you check that?

Comment: The free memory goes down to 14-15 MB and stay still to that value until the compilation fails. How you guessed that from the error messages?

Comment: The "Killed" in *"g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program
 cc1plus)"* is a strong hint. More modern versions of gcc would probably (hopefully) have given a clearer error message.